# How do I get my java applets to work again

Tags: java, security, permissions, applet, manifest

So the java applets on my website stop working. I try updating browsers on all my computers (mac and windows), still the problem persists. Then as I did more research, I learn that I have to [change my manifest](http://java.com/en/download/faq/signed_code.xml). Does anyone have an example of what the new manifest should look like? Is there anything else I need to do? Please, please, provide an example. I have been [reading about the new requirements](http://java.com/en/download/help/index.xml), but I am still not clear on how to implement the changes.

Comment: These applets have been on my website since 2011. I changed nothing. I updated nothing. This month they stopped working. As I say in the OP, my research shows that the requirements for publishing applets have changed precisely this month: january 2014. So if anyone has successfully gotten their "old" applets to work with this new requirements, please share.

Answer (score 1):

So, your **Applets** must contain two things:

> 1. Code signatures from a trusted authority. All code for **Applets** must
>      be signed, regardless of its `Permissions` attributes.
> 2. Manifest Attributes
>
>    a.  `Permissions` – Introduced in **7u25**, and required as of
>      **7u51**. Indicates if the **Applets** should run within the sandbox or require full-permissions.
>
>    b. `Codebase` – Introduced in **7u25** and optional/encouraged as of
>      **7u51**. Points to the known location of the hosted code.

Sample of `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_51
Permissions: sandbox
Codebase: www.java.com java.com
```

More information here

- [**New security requirements for RIAs in 7u51 (January 2014)**](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias)